# HTML/CSS Inline-block div alignment

Tags: html, css

First of all I've just started writing in HTML and CSS so my question might be very simple. I've provided 2 JSFiddle links which hopefully show what my problem is.  What I basically want to achieve is that my buttons div is aligned with my logo div and that they're centered horizontally. In the logo div I plan on only using a background image. 
In [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/10921/) they seem to align but I have to use a text in the logo div.

And [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/10922/) is how it looks when I remove the text. (not aligned as I would want).

Here's the HTML Code

```
<html>
<head>
     <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron:400,700,900,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<div id="logo">x</div>
<div id="buttons">
<div class="button">Button1</div>
<div class="button">Button2</div>
<div class="button">Button3</div>
<div class="button">Button4</div>
<div class="button">Button5</div>
</div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

For some reason I can't format properly the CSS code so please check the links for it.

EDIT:

```
#header{
width: 100vw;
min-width: 1280px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #191919;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
}
#logo{
width: 400px;
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: 0;
color: #ffffff;
display: inline-block;
}
#buttons{
height: 100%;
width: 800px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: 0;
display: inline-block;
}
.buttons{
height: 100%;
width: 160px;
font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
font-weight: 900;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
color: #ffffff;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Please post the CSS in your question and attempt to format it. If there's an issue any user with enough privileges can fix it. Without the CSS your question loses its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/10924/

Add this to CSS

```
#logo {
  float: left;
}

#logo img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

EDIT

Also you will get this https://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/10926/ if you remove `width: 400;` from `#logo`

EDIT 2

Center buttons https://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/10927/

Comment: That worked thank you. However what I also want is to have both logo div and buttons div centered horizontally. On a higher resolution screen, the logo now always remains on the left side of the screen while the buttons somewhat center themselves if I use text-align: center in the #header.

Comment: You can put logo and buttons inside one `div` and set `width` and `margin: 0 auto;` on that div

Comment: I've got them both inside header div already which has width set to 100vw and I tried using `margin:0 auto;` instead of `margin: 0` but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Thank you that worked great. If you have the time can you also kindly explain what you did? From what I can see the only major difference is using `vertical-align: middle` but shouldn't they be aligned by default?

Comment: Good question and i am not sure. You set inline align with `display: inline-block` but i think you need to set `vertical-align: middle` for vertical align, but i might be wrong. If this fixed your problem accept the anwser.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML structure isn't particularly nice. But this code alone will get everything inline.

```
#header div {display:inline-block;}
```

Alternatively:

```
#logo {float:left;}
#buttons {float:left;}
#buttons .button {display:inline-block;}
```

This is better practice as it displays just your button list inline which provides more flexibility with your logo and other elements.

Comment: While it did align the logo div and the buttons div quite nicely , I can't figure out how to center them horizontally now.

Comment: I'd suggest posting your updated code with a bit more information on how you want it to look specifically. Quite hard to say how best to center as there are a range of techniques that can be used.